# Deleting Private Folders for Reports and Dashboards

Tags: folder

I have been asked to delete all empty Private Folders for reports and dashboards, then delete the rest of the Private Folders after a certain date. Is it possible to delete Private Folders, even in the API?

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383270&type=1), Use the "allPrivate" query scope to find Reports and Dashboards in private folders

To return reports in private folders:
SELECT Id FROM Report USING SCOPE allPrivate

To query reports inside a specific User's private folder (replace the user ID below as appropriate):
SELECT Id FROM Report USING SCOPE allPrivate WHERE OwnerId = '005A0000000Bc2deFG'

To query Dynamic Dashboards that are stored within Private Folders:
SELECT Id FROM Dashboard USING SCOPE allPrivate WHERE Type != 'SpecifiedUser'

To return the owner name or determine if a user is inactive:

1. Select "Allows SOQL Parent Relationship Queries"
2. Run the following query:

SELECT Id, Owner.Name FROM Report USING SCOPE allPrivate WHERE Owner.IsActive = false

Also check [delete Report or Dashboard from Private or Personal folder](https://www.salesforcesathish.com/how-to-delete-report-or-dashboard-from-private-or-personal-folder-in-salesforce/)  using workbench or dataloader.